# Posting to twitter

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have problem in posting to twitter, where it only posting to my account
The following is how i implemented it :

Declare at the class: `private ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder;`

placed it at when the form open method :

```
    configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("*****")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("*****")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("******")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("*****");
```

Placed at action listener for a Button:

```
  try {
        if (jTextPane.getSelectedText().length() <= 127) {
            TwitterFactory twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(configurationBuilder.build());
            Twitter twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
            Status status = twitter.updateStatus("#polytechnic " + jTextPane.getSelectedText());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tweet Posted Successfully.");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can tweet 127 character only.");
        }
    } catch (TwitterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PolyNote.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

from my research i knew that the problem is in using access token keys, however i couldn't find away to configure it without it!!